# Does Office 365 or Outlook support Google Apps feature "Reply from the same address the message was sent to"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, gmail, office365, google-workspace

I've been using Google Apps for years.
Now I am thinking about switching to Outlook.com/Office 365. **Note: I am not and won't be using Outlook for Windows.**

The one feature I find invaluable with GMail is **"Reply from the same address the message was sent to"**.
The only thing I do to set this up is in Settings->Accounts I need to add an alias email. Easy enough.

I don't have to do anything else. When I reply, the From: address is automatically set to the address the email was sent to. Great!

Does Microsoft in Office 365 (I'm not interested in Outlook for Windows, I wouldn't use that) offer the same feature without having to go through a complicated setup or hack?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Outlook for Web Access will just reply using your default e-mail address. I added my gmail account and they loaded into the inbox.

In Outlook for Web Access, the from ended up being my work e-mail.

If I use Outlook for Windows (newer versions anyway, such as 2013/2016 and maybe 2007/2010) it pretends to have the correct FROM e-mail, but unless you've actually added that account to Outlook (Windows), it'll just use the default e-mail address.

Outlook for Web Access (OWA) is a competent web mail client, but the features diverge quite a bit from Gmail.

Personally, I think you'll be disappointed with any type of switch from Google Apps as it relates to replying back with the correct FROM.

Comment: To Add to @LunaMezza it's pretty difficult to setup.  In Outlook to use an Alias we needed to connect a 2nd account thru POP, and disable the email checking, this allowed it be selected as an address. Other options are creating the alias on a distribution group or shared folder and granting yoru self "send as" permissions.  None of these is ideal.

Comment: @LunaMezza thanks for your input. I'm sticking with Gmail then. No alternative.